# Can't access NFS via GNOME Nautilus. (Mountpoint does not exist)

Tags: gnome, nfs, nautilus

I have NFS server. I can mount it manually:

```
sudo mount -t nfs myserver:/srv/nfs /mnt
```

But I can also mount it with file managers, as I'm broadcasting its presence using avahi. I can mount it via thunar (xfce's file manager), but I'm not able to access it via GNOME's Nautilus.

Nautilus says:

```
Unable to access location: Mountpoint does not exist.
```

GVFS log says:

```
nfs: Added new job source 0x55c37a44e2f0 (GVfsBackendNfs)
nfs: Queued new job 0x55c37a43cf30 (GVfsJobMount)
nfs: send_reply(0x55c37a43cf30), failed=1 (Mountpoint does not exist)
```

Server side /etc/exports:

```
# /etc/exports - exports(5) - directories exported to NFS clients
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
#  /srv/home        hostname1(rw,sync) hostname2(ro,sync)
# Example for NFSv4:
#  /srv/nfs4        hostname1(rw,sync,fsid=0)
#  /srv/nfs4/home   hostname1(rw,sync,nohide)
# Using Kerberos and integrity checking:
#  /srv/nfs4        *(rw,sync,sec=krb5i,fsid=0)
#  /srv/nfs4/home   *(rw,sync,sec=krb5i,nohide)
#
# Use `exportfs -arv` to reload.

/srv/nfs 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,insecure)
```

Server side /etc/avahi/services/nfs.service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
  <!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
  <service-group>
    <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h-nfs</name>
    <service>
      <type>_nfs._tcp</type>
      <port>2049</port>
      <txt-record>path=/srv/nfs</txt-record>
    </service>
</service-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and I might have found out why. It might be because of [NFSv4 not supported](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/18)